# toggleClass() not working for div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been working on a website and run into a problem. In my FAQ, I have a drop-down menu and a submit button to link to different parts of the FAQ. This works perfectly. The submit button triggers a javascript function which dynamically links to the appropriate anchor on the page. In addition, I want the question chosen by the drop down menu to be highlighted orange. I got the highlight to show up, but only for a split second before it flashes away. I am wondering how to make the highlight stay, instead of flash away? I am not certain why this is happening. In addition, how could I make the highlight fade in using jQuery? I know how to do it through hiding the div then using .fade(), but that results in all of the text disappearing. Thanks so much!

heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UjPtv/ but it doesn't work fully because when you submit it comes up with an error. I think this is because jsfiddle doesn't allow submit's, even though this submit is simply running some javascript. If you know a way around please let me know so I can update the link! Thanks!

javascript:

```
var toggled = 0;
function jump_to (location) {
if(toggled == 0){
    toggled = 1;
    window.location.href = "#" + location;
    $("#wrap"+location).toggleClass("wraps_active");
}
}​
```

html:

```
<div id = "main">
        <h2 class = "center">FACTS YOU NEED</h2>
        <h3>The Core Facts You Want To Know</h3>
        <div class = "border">
        <p>
            Jump To: 
              <form onsubmit = "jump_to(jump_list.value)">
              <select name = "jump_list">
              <option value="1">Who can go to the camp?</option>
              <option value="2"><a href = "contact_information.html">When do we check in and out?</a></option>
            </select>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Go"/>
            </form>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id = "wrap1" class = "wraps">
        <h4><a name = "1"></a>Who can go to the camp? </h4>
        <p>
            The camp is for kids ages 9 to 17 years old who have been diagnosed with celiac disease, a condition that requires life-long adherence to a gluten-free diet.  Given limited space, we are unable to accommodate kids on gluten-free diets for other reasons (such as autism spectrum disorders).  Campers ages 16-17 years may choose to volunteer as junior counselors.  Junior counselors assist the adult volunteers, and for first session junior counselors need to arrive a day early (on Monday) for the staff orientation and training.  If there are more junior counselor applicants than there is available space, priority is given based on age, gender-need, and prior camp experience.
        </p>
        </div>
        <div id = "wrap2" class = "wraps">
        <h4><a name = "2"></a>When do we check in and out?</h4>
        <p>
            Check-in: Please see the "Calendar" on the left hand side of the website for details about each camp.Please do not arrive early.
            </br><br/>
            Check-out:  All campers must be checked out by the stated time so camp can be prepared for the next group, see the "Calendar" for date information.
        </p>
        </div>


    </div>​
```

css:

```
.wraps{
border-bottom:1px dashed #C3C3C3;
}
.wraps_active{
border-bottom:1px dashed #C3C3C3;
background:#FFB280;
}​
```

Comment: The second parameter of the `.toggleClass()` method accepts a boolean to toggle it the way you want for certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime the form is submitted, clean all of the active wrap classes and add it only for the selected one.

```
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = $('select[name=jump_list]').val();
    window.location.href = "#" + location;

    $('.wraps').removeClass('wraps_active');
    $("#wrap"+location).addClass("wraps_active");
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjPtv/7/).

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 $("#wrap"+location).addClass("wraps_active");
```

instead of `toggleClass`

Comment: thank you for your response! I tried that, but the same problem persisted.